# figure does not appear, however \includegraphics{} does

Tags: floats, multicol

I'd like to insert `figure`-environments into my tex document, however the figures do not appear after compiling the file. On the other hand I can includes images without any problems.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

% paper geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=15mm,
    right=15mm,
    top=15mm,
    bottom=20mm
}

% header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE] {Test}
\fancyfoot[C]{-\,\thepage\,-}

% including images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

% columns
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnseprule0.5pt
\columnsep5mm

% german spelling
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

% blind text for mwe
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\section*{Test}
\blindtext
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example.eps}
\blindtext\\
\textbf{FIGURE HERE}\\
\begin{figure}
\caption{example}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example.eps}
\end{figure}
\blindtext


\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I compile this file with: `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test`

Comment: The `figure` environment is to blame here. The first image appears (at least with a local `example.eps`, but the second is wrapped into a floating `figure` environment, which is not allowed in `multicols` environment (well, ignored rather)

Comment: You do get the warning `Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside \`multicols' 
environment!`